# Difference between Layers and Pipes and filters?

Tags: design-patterns

What is difference between these two design patterns? It seems very similar to me, one processing unit (layer or filter) do some data procession and pull / push data into another processing unit. Unit `n` communicates only with `n+1` and `n-1` unit, there are interfaces defining functionality that one particular unit offers.

What is difference?

**Edit:** maybe one difference should be the data flow. In Layers flow can be `top-down`, `bottom-up` and/or communication `between` some layers inside. In Pipes and filters data flow starts at unit `1` and goes to unit `n` (not back).

Comment: I would say there is huge conceptual difference.
(1) Layers pattern is more of building a stack. For example, take typical JEE, you start from resource layer, then data, business ending in presentation. (2) Pipe and filter is for processing, transforming and filtering data step by step. An example would be a message pipe.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Organization wise it may looks like both Layers and Pipe and Filters patters are similar (One component taking input and passing result to another) but functionally they are not. They are Architectural Patterns.

If we go by **definition**:

Pipes and Filters pattern divide a larger processing task into a sequence of smaller, independent processing steps (Filters) that are connected by channels (Pipes).

While in Layer Pattern, each layer communicates with the adjacent layers and is responsible for some processing of its own, passing requests to the layer below it and answering requests from the layer above it.

**Comparison**:

The pipe and filter pattern allows a system to be assembled from small programs called filters **whereas**  a Layered system is one in which different layers of the system take care of a specific function of the system.

A filter has an input and an output **whereas** each layer in a layered architectural style is a package of software (or systems) that has a well-defined interface and a few well-known dependencies within the application.

The filters are assembled into a chain in which each filter gets data from the previous filter in the chain, processes the data, and passes the data to the next filter in the chain **whereas** in Layered systems dataflow can be bidirectional such that all requests of layer above are fulfilled *with or without* help of layers below it.

Order may not matter. e.g. you can Authenticate a message and then filter the contents of the message, or you can filter contents first then do authentication **whereas** in Layered system order is always same and cannot be interchanged.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

There is no structural difference, only differences in intention and metaphor to conjure up different pictures in the mind.

The intention for a layered architecture (up/down metaphor) is generally about mapping through different levels of abstraction, e.g. from business-level concepts through to low-level network or database operations and back again.

The intention for pipes and filters (plumbing metaphor) is generally about transformations at a similar level of abstraction.